# Google Cloud container orchestration and cleanup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In short, I am looking to see if it is possible to run multiple Docker containers on the same machine via gcloud's `create-with-container` functionality (or similar).  The idea is that there will be some "worker" container (which does some arbitrary work) which runs and completes, followed by a "cleanup" container which subsequently runs performing the same task each time.

#### Longer explanation:

I currently have an application that launches tasks that run inside Docker containers on Google Cloud.  I use `gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container <...other args...>` to launch the VM, which runs the specified container.  I will call that the "worker" container, and the tasks it performs are not relevant to my question.  However, regardless of the "worker" container, I would like to run a second, "cleanup" container upon the completion of the first.  In this way, developers can write independently write Docker containers that do not have to "repeat" the work done by the "cleanup" container.

**Side note**:

I know that I could alternatively specify a startup script (e.g. a bash script) which starts the docker containers as I describe above.  However, when I first tried that, I kept running into issues where the `docker pull <image>` command would timeout or fail for some reason when communicating with dockerhub.  The `gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container <...args...>` seemed to have error handling/retries built-in, which seemed ideal.  Does anyone have a working snippet that would provide relatively robust error handling in the startup script?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the limitation is one container per VM instance. See [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: It is currently not possible to launch multiple containers with the `create-with-container` functionality.

**Alternative**: You mentioned that you have already tried launching your containers with a startup script. Another option would be to specify a [cloud-init config through instance metadata](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#using_cloud-init). Cloud-init is built into Container-Optimized OS (the same OS that you would use with `create-with-container`).

It works by adding and starting a systemd service, which means that you can:

- specify that your service should run after other services: `network-online.target` and `docker.socket`
- specify a [Restart policy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) for the service to do retries on failure,
- add an [ExecStopPost](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=) specification to run your cleanup (or add a separate service for that in the cloud-init config)

This is a snippet that could be a starting point (you would need to add it under `user-data` metadata key):

```
#cloud-config

users:
- name: cloudservice
  uid: 2000

write_files:
- path: /etc/systemd/system/cloudservice.service
  permissions: 0644
  owner: root
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Start a simple docker container
    Wants=network-online.target docker.socket
    After=network-online.target docker.socket

    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm -u 2000 --name=cloudservice busybox:latest /bin/sleep 180
    ExecStopPost=/bin/echo Finished!
    Restart=on-failure
    RestartSec=30

runcmd:
- systemctl daemon-reload
- systemctl start cloudservice.service
```